# v-if behave differently: from vue project 1.x to 2.x migration

Tags: vue.js

In my vue project, i am tring to upgrade from 1.x to 2.x. And I come across a problem as following:

```
<div id="demo">
  <service :service-name="serviceName" ref="testcomp" v-if="runTest"></service>
</div>
```

on the child component `service`, I use `v-if` to control its existence. And in the parent component, I want to use `this.$refs.testcomp` to invoke the method `test` defined inside the child component as following:

```
  methods: {
    init() {
        this.runTest = true;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  watch: {
    runTest() {
        if(this.runTest)  {
        console.log('1');
        this.$refs.testcomp.test();
        console.log('2');
      }
    },
  },
```

But the error  message said that `this.$refs.testcomp` is undefined. I have created the live demo with jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/0r4vby5n/1/

But in vue1.x, it can work well. https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/fzuajwkz/1/

I know change to v-show, can skip this issue. But in my real project(it is an big project, developed by others. So if i change v-if to v-show, it will trigger other issues related to work flow). So is there any way to make the v-if still work in the upgraded version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because when you called this.$refs.testcomp.test() the element is not ready yet. Try doing this instead:

```
this.$nextTick(() =>{
    this.$refs.testcomp.test();
})
```

Comment: thanks, it works. inside the nexttick callback, the element is ready.